# Pass @Published var by reference to function from View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on a registration screen which has a ViewModel attached to it.

The ViewModel is just a class which extends my registration screen class, where I place all of my business logic.

```
extension RegistrationScreen {
    @MainActor class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
         //business logic goes here
    }
}
```

The ViewModel has @Published variables to represent two states for every text field in the screen: text and validationText.

```
 @Published var first: String = ""
 @Published var firstValidationMessage: String = ""
```

within that ViewModel I have a call to a helper function from another class which checks to see if the field's text is empty and if so it can set the fields validation text to an error, that looks like this:

```
class FieldValidation: Identifiable {


func isFieldEmptyAndSetError(fieldText:String, fieldValidationText:Binding<String>) -> Bool {
    
    if(fieldText.isEmpty){
        fieldValidationText.wrappedValue = "Required"
        return true
    }else{
        fieldValidationText.wrappedValue = ""
        return false
    }
}
}
```

to call that function from my viewModel I do the following:

```
FieldValidation().isFieldEmptyAndSetError(fieldText:first,fieldValidationText: firstValidationMessage)
```

This is throwing runtime errors which are hard to decrypt for me since I am new to Xcode and iOS in general.

My question is, how can I get this passing by reference to work? alternatively if the way I am doing is not possible please explain what is going on.

Comment: well I created a class called ViewModel and extended registration screen with it, not the same as ViewModel in android but for the purposes of this question that is what I meant by it, I can post that code if you think it would help

Comment: you have to learn the View data struct and @ State and @ Binding, we don't use view model objects in SwiftUI

Comment: I already make use of @ State and @ Binding, if view models are not used then do you keep all of the view logic in the UI file or is there a different pattern?

Comment: View structs aren’t the UI. SwiftUI diffs the structs and updates the UI on screen like UILabels, UITableViews etc for us. You can put related vars and logic you want to test into their own @State struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of weird having a function that receives a `@Published` as a parameter, if you want to handle all the validations in the viewModel, this seems as an easy solution for `Combine`. I would suggest you to create an extension to validate if the string is empty, since `.isEmpty` does not trim the text.

The class

```
  class FieldValidation: Identifiable {
    
    
    static func isFieldEmptyAndSetError(fieldText:String) -> String {
        return fieldText.isEmpty ?  "Required" : ""
    }
}
```

The view Model

```
    import Foundation
import Combine

class viewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text1 = ""
    @Published var text2 = ""
    @Published var text3 = ""
    @Published var validationText1 = ""
    @Published var validationText2 = ""
    @Published var validationText3 = ""
    
    init() {
        self.$text1.map{newText in  FieldValidation.isFieldEmptyAndSetError(fieldText: newText)}.assign(to: &$validationText1)
        
        self.$text2.map{newText in  FieldValidation.isFieldEmptyAndSetError(fieldText: newText)}.assign(to: &$validationText2)
        
    }

     func validateText(value: String) {
        self.validationText3 = FieldValidation.isFieldEmptyAndSetError(fieldText: value)
    }
}
```

The view would look like this:

```
      import SwiftUI

    struct ViewDate: View {
        @StateObject var myviewModel = viewModel()
        
        var body: some View {
            
            VStack{
                Text("Fill the next fields:")
                
                TextField("", text: $myviewModel.text1)
                    .border(Color.red)
                Text(myviewModel.validationText1)
                
                TextField("", text: $myviewModel.text2)
                    .border(Color.blue)
                Text(myviewModel.validationText2)
                
                TextField("", text: $myviewModel.text3)
                    .border(Color.green)
                    .onChange(of: myviewModel.text3) { newValue in
                        if(newValue.isEmpty){
                            self.myviewModel.validateText(value: newValue)
                        }
                    }
                Text(myviewModel.validationText3)
            }.padding()
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to make the start value be "" so the text will only have something to display if the user has changed its corresponding textfield value?

Comment: Yes with the onChange modifier on the Textfield, you'll have to remove the another validation. I updated the answer.